# Spring Boot and SAML 2.0

Tags: spring, saml-2.0, spring-boot

Is there a way to integrate SAML 2.0 in a Spring Boot-based application?
I'd like to implement my own SP and communicate with a remote IdP.

Answer (score 15):

I recently released a spring boot plugin for this [here](https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/spring-boot-security-saml). It is basically a wrapper around Spring Security SAML that allows for friendlier configuration through a DSL or config properties. Here's an example using the DSL:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSAMLSSO
public class SpringBootSecuritySAMLDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootSecuritySAMLDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class MyServiceProviderConfig extends ServiceProviderConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void configure(ServiceProviderSecurityBuilder serviceProvider) throws Exception {
            serviceProvider
                .metadataGenerator()
                .entityId("localhost-demo")
            .and()
                .sso()
                .defaultSuccessURL("/home")
                .idpSelectionPageURL("/idpselection")
            .and()
                .logout()
                .defaultTargetURL("/")
            .and()
                .metadataManager()
                .metadataLocations("classpath:/idp-ssocircle.xml")
                .refreshCheckInterval(0)
            .and()
                .extendedMetadata()
                .idpDiscoveryEnabled(true)
            .and()
                .keyManager()
                .privateKeyDERLocation("classpath:/localhost.key.der")
                .publicKeyPEMLocation("classpath:/localhost.cert");

        }
    }
}
```

That's basically all the code you need.

Comment: can this be used for Spring Boot based Rest API ?

Comment: I think this answer should be accepted as the best answer, since it shows a more advanced integration with Spring Boot Autoconfiguration, and moreover, it's based on @vdenotaris' work.

It's pretty amazing btw that the SAML extension of Spring Security is not yet officially integrated with Spring Boot.

Comment: Would this configuration work if you were also supporting an angularjs front end in the same application as the spring boot rest service?

Answer (score 3):

You'd have to do all the SAML stuff in XML (surprise, surprise). But the rest shouldn't get in the way, just standard Springy, Booty stuff, e.g.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@ImportResource("my-crazy-ass-saml.xml")
public class Application implements WebMvcSecurityAdapter {

    // set up security filter chain here

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried @vdenotaris' solution, but does not seem to work with current spring-boot, and thus given up that approach.

So as an alternate solution I used shibboleth to do all the SAML stuff using the `mod_shib2` module in apache httpd, and run tomcat using `mod_jk` (mod_proxy_ajp could also be used) behind the said apache instance. Tomcat receives all the required SAML attributes as request attributes, and I only have to store the idp and the user id in the regular user table to connect the internal authentication to the external (I need both SAML and password-based authentication).

Comment: The compatibility with the new version of Spring Boot is on my to-do list, but currently you should use the project as is.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not really an option as we have already a large project built on top of the current version of spring-boot; thus my above outlined solution. Other solution would be to use spring-saml in another servlet and authenticate using some improvised inter-servlet protocol. That would be even less nice. :(