# Sample SAML Java Config. Project, Broken From the Start

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I pulled in the example [Java configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-java) [project](https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample) for Spring's SAML extension. No commits seem to have been made to the project for about six months as of my writing this question. I have not done anything to this project except for run `maven package` against it.

I then run the application in Spring Tool Suite as a Spring Boot Application and the application runs; however, the application does not run without error and the application endpoint is inaccessible (resulting in am error message): "ERROR: Something went wrong in the authentication process".

I haven't registered any certificates, etc (and may very well need to). There are no instructions provided with the GitHub project for starting or working with the application. I have intentionally not posted the guts of the project as I have left it unmodified.

#### INFORMATION ON THE ERROR

From Chrome Dev. Tools, I can see a `500 Internal Server Error` returned from the request to the `localhost:8080` application. So, the issue is definitely with the sample application (or something that I have not done).

The following error is logged to the console *on application deployment* (I've included both an image and the text as the text is proving difficult to format):

[image: Error logged to console]

Text:

> **[2015-08-20 14:41:40.551] boot - 9908  INFO [localhost-startStop-1]**
>   --- HttpMethodDirector: I/O exception (javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException) caught when processing
>   request: SSL peer failed hostname validation for name: 46.4.112.4
>   **[2015-08-20 14:41:40.551] boot - 9908  INFO [localhost-startStop-1]**
>   --- HttpMethodDirector: Retrying request
>   **[2015-08-20 14:41:40.795] boot - 9908 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1]** --- HTTPMetadataProvider:
>   Error retrieving metadata from https://idp.ssocircle.com/idp-meta.xml
>   **javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: SSL peer failed hostname
>   validation for name: 46.4.112.4**
>   at org.opensaml.ws.soap.client.http.TLSProtocolSocketFactory.verifyHostname(TLSProtocolSocketFactory.java:233)
>   at
>   org.opensaml.ws.soap.client.http.TLSProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(TLSProtocolSocketFactory.java:194)

I have visited the url endpoint provided by ssocircle and the metadata is exposed.

If I visit the `/saml/metadata` endpoint of the service provider and get some helpful information: an `org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException` exception. The description if which is "No IDP was configured, please update included metadata with at least one IDP"; however, the source of this may be the above described error.

#### QUESTION

Am I missing something that is readily apparent to start the example application? In other words, what does this error tell me that I need to be investigating? Or, as it is "non-breaking", do I ignore it?

#### WHY I'M ASKING

The documentation surrounding the deployment of the Sample Java Configuration application is minimal (as in "non-existant"). The self-documentation only provides "hints", such as the following:

```
 // IDP Metadata configuration - paths to metadata of IDPs in circle of trust is here
 // Do no forget to call initialize method on providers
 @Bean
 @Qualifier("metadata")
 public CachingMetadataManager metadata() throws MetadataProviderException {
      List<MetadataProvider> providers = new ArrayList<MetadataProvider>();
      providers.add(ssoCircleExtendedMetadataProvider());
      return new CachingMetadataManager(providers);
 }
```

I am certain there is something I am not doing, particularly since I have not done anything in the deployment of the application except for the run of the `mvn package`, described above.

Comment: I am entirely new to Spring SAML. Any comments to help me improve the question are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs due to the sample application's utilization of a deprecated constructor - a deprecation whose warning was explicitly suppressed - for the `HTTPMetadataProvider` (a fix I will commit, shortly). In configuring the `ExtendedMetadataDelegate`, the [two-parametered constructor](https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/org/opensaml/opensaml/2.5.3/opensaml-2.5.3-javadoc.jar/!/org/opensaml/saml2/metadata/provider/HTTPMetadataProvider.html#HTTPMetadataProvider(java.lang.String,%20int)) is utilized:

```
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("idp-ssocircle")
    public ExtendedMetadataDelegate ssoCircleExtendedMetadataProvider() throws MetadataProviderException {  
        @SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation"})
        HTTPMetadataProvider httpMetadataProvider = new HTTPMetadataProvider("https://idp.ssocircle.com/idp-meta.xml", 5000);
        // other config.s...
    }
```

If replaced with the non-deprecated constructor that takes a `java.util.Timer` and an `org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient` (in addition to the metadata url), the sample application works, beautifully, and no errors are logged.

#### Additional Non-OP-related Information

*I had to do the below to get the Sample SAML app to run*

After removing the deprecated constructor, I recommend doing two things:

1. Follow the steps outlined in [4.2.6 of the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#quick-start-sp-metadata-to-idp), i.e. treat the application during setup as the XML-configured application. All the steps need to be taken to "register" the metada.**The application will be unable to register its metadata with the current Java configuration (see below; point no. 2)**
2. Change the default configurations in class `WebSecurityConfig` (read detail, below)

**Configuration Change**

In the configuration of the `ExtendedMetadataDelegate` bean `ssoCircleExtendedMetadataProvider`, change the `ExtendedMetadataDelegate`'s property values as follows:

```
// code....
extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataTrustCheck(true);
extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataRequireSignature(false);
// code....
```

In the `ExtendedMetadata` bean (different from above), change the property values as below:

```
// code....
extendedMetadata.setIdpDiscoveryEnabled(true); 
extendedMetadata.setSignMetadata(false);
// code....
```

#### "Disclaimer"

Whether or not this should be used in production, I do not know; however, it seems to better reflect both the XML-based configuration and resulting metadata of the XML-configured Service Provider example referenced in the [SAML Spring Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/)

Comment: I tried below lines but it is still not working can you help ?         Timer timer = new Timer();
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        HTTPMetadataProvider httpMetadataProvider = new HTTPMetadataProvider(timer, httpClient, "https://idp.ssocircle.com/idp-meta.xml");

Comment: I get "Reason: Unable to do Single Sign On or Federation."

Comment: @aProgrammer yes. There are some other configurations that are affecting the ability for the sample SAML application to produce metadata that is acceptable by ssocircle (I do not know whether that is based on ssocircle not parsing correctly or Spring's Java configuration producing bad XML - my inclination is that it is the latter). I am going to test on Microsoft Azure, later. Also, the `HttpClient` that I am using is that which is initialized as a `@Bean` with the `MultiThreadConnectionManager` passed to its constructor.

Comment: @aProgrammer check out the changes to the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just some hints:

I met this exception when I was trying to set up the HTTP-Artifact profile.

There is a hostnameVerifier in `org.opensaml.ws.soap.client.http.TLSProtocolSocketFactory` (openws-1.5.1) and a `verifyHostname()` processing before OpenSAML tries to create socket to connect to other host.

I configured `sslHostnameVerification` to "allowAll" in `org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata`, the allowed values are "default", "defaultAndLocalhost", "strict", and "allowAll".

It seems in your case, this exception was thrown when the SP (your saml sample) was trying to download the *metadata.xml* from IdP (ssocircle). The best way to figure out what is happening is to debug when and where the `hostnameVerifier` was set.

Or you can try set sslHostnameVerification to "allowAll" in the SSOCircle's ExtendedMetadataDelegate's ExtendedMetadata to have a try first..

Answer (score 0):

checkout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37381750/2139222): It basically describes a plugin I recently released that allows you to configure Spring Boot and Spring Security SAML this way:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSAMLSSO
public class SpringBootSecuritySAMLDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootSecuritySAMLDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class MyServiceProviderConfig extends ServiceProviderConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void configure(ServiceProviderSecurityBuilder serviceProvider) throws Exception {
            serviceProvider
                .metadataGenerator()
                .entityId("localhost-demo")
            .and()
                .sso()
                .defaultSuccessURL("/home")
                .idpSelectionPageURL("/idpselection")
            .and()
                .logout()
                .defaultTargetURL("/")
            .and()
                .metadataManager()
                .metadataLocations("classpath:/idp-ssocircle.xml")
                .refreshCheckInterval(0)
            .and()
                .extendedMetadata()
                .idpDiscoveryEnabled(true)
            .and()
                .keyManager()
                .privateKeyDERLocation("classpath:/localhost.key.der")
                .publicKeyPEMLocation("classpath:/localhost.cert");

        }
    }
}
```

There are a couple Demo apps integrated with SSO Circle

Comment: What is entityId ? here you defined "localhost-demo"